# Do I need UK transit visa to going to Ireland?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, ireland, iranian-citizens

I am Iranian and I have Irish visa. I am going to Cork from Tehran. I will have one stop in LHR London Heathrow airport for 7 hours. Do I need any type of visa to stay in airport in London? Could I leave the airport in these 7 hours?

There is another flight that needs changing airport in London (LTN London Luton to LHR London Heathrow). Could I use this flight?

I found some similar questions but I couldn't get the exact answer.

Comment: What kind of Irish Visa do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately the [UK website](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa) is quite comprehensive and useful in this case. If you wish to leave the airport i.e you exit out of the airport (in this case to travel to another airport), this is called a Landside transit. You **will need a [visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) in order to do so i.e for the LTN to LHR transit**.

As pointed out by @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, unfortunately the case of Ireland is a little bit more complicated than you would imagine. This is due to the **[CTA or Common Travel Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area)** agreement. Underneath CTA, the flights leaving from British Airports to Ireland are considered *short-haul international flights*.

Thus, they depart from the **domestic** terminal instead. In order to do this you **will need a landside transit visa**. More information can be found on the [Heathrow Airport website](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/flight-connections/connection-guides/international-arrival-ireland-departure) and the [Gatwick Airport website](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/Flight-Connections/) which clearly state this information as well.

If you were an Iranian Citizen traveling to Ireland *somehow without passing thru border control* i.e doing an airside transit, [this link would have applied to you](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/iran/transit/no).

One thing to note here is the exemptions. You would have been exempted from the visa if you were to have:

> a valid uniform format category D visa for entry to a state in
>   the European Economic Area (EEA)

Ireland counts as a state in the EEA and thus if you have a [category D visa for Ireland](http://ireland.angloinfo.com/moving/residency/long-stay-visas/) (i.e a long stay visa) , you don't not need a Direct Airside Transit Visa for the UK.

**In all other cases, otherwise you will need a landside visa and as far as I can see, the only way to get to Ireland from the UK involves passing thru border control at the airport.**

Comment: @Mojtaba Not a problem. :D

Comment: There is such thing as CTA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area). OP *will have* to go through passport control in order to proceed to Ireland because from the point of view of British law, flights to Ireland are *domestic*. Therefore the third link in your answer must have been (https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/iran/transit/yes).

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy You're right. It seems I missed this point. It's completely possible that the flight to Ireland leaves from the domestic terminal and in that case, the OP **must** get a landsite transit visa but then this also means that the OP should technically not require any immigration in Ireland. My past experience tell me that this is not true. When I visited Ireland from Manchester as an Indian Citizen, my passport was *stamped* with a separate Irish Visa on arrival without regard to CTA which holds true only for Irish/British Citizens.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Answer revised. My research confirms your thought! Thanks!

Comment: @AdityaSomani, "then this also means that the OP should technically not require any immigration in Ireland" - that is not so. AFAIK, all passengers arriving at Dublin airport have to undergo passport control - even if they arrive from Kerry!

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy You're correct. They just do it at both places even though they have the CTA. Britain be weird.

Comment: Oh! It means although I have Long stay Irish visa (D), I can't go Ireland via England because I should change terminal in Heathrow airport. OK?

Comment: @Mojtaba Correct.

Comment: @Mojtaba no, if you have an Irish visa type D you "might be eligible for the ‘transit without visa concession’".

Comment: @Mojtaba see https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/iran/transit/yes

Comment: @rsanchez, You are right I don't need transit visa If I don't change my terminal. Unfortunately Ireland flights are from domestic terminal and I will arrive in international terminal, so I need to change terminal.

Comment: @Mojtaba the link I pasted says you can be exempted even if you cross Border Control. Please read all the information carefully.

Comment: @rsanchez I won't risk something that important on chance when the visa is 50 pounds and will not be hard to get at all. I'd suggest you to apply and get the visa.

Comment: @rsanchez, I checked your link again and it seems I could go to Ireland via London without any type of visa (even change airport or a short trip less than 24 hours in London) but I am afraid of last sentence "The ‘transit without visa concession’ is decided by the immigration officer at the border. You won’t be allowed to transit if they decide you need a visa, so you might want to apply for a transit visa before you travel."

Comment: @AdityaSomani, 50 pounds is much for me :). So I am thinking for other methods. Could you check another question that I asked [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27865/do-i-need-any-visa-to-transit-via-ukrine-and-amsterdam)

Answer (score 1):

You will generally need a visa, whether you [stay airside](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/iran/transit/no) (don't leave the transit area of the airport) or [go landside](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/iran/transit/yes) (go through passport check, e.g. to collect your bags or leave the airport).

There are exemptions (to the direct airside transit visa requirement) and you could then also apply for a transit without visa concession (to go landside) but only if your Irish visa is a long-stay visa or if you have a residence permit for Ireland (so basically if you are going to reside there for some time, not merely visit).

Comment: Due to the CTA, travel to Ireland counts as domestic for immigration purposes, so you'll still have to clear immigration no matter what (landside or airside) - it'll be the same process as X -> London -> eg Newcastle