# Do I need any visa for transit via Amsterdam?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, netherlands, ireland

I have an Iranian passport and Irish D type visa. I am planning to go to Cork from Tehran. I found these two flights in order to reach Cork:

Tehran → Kiev → Amsterdam (27June, One Way): [Flight Numbers: PS 0752 and PS 9386](http://www.flyuia.com/eng/information-and-services/destinations/book-flights-amds.html)

Amsterdam → Cork: [Flight Number: EI845](http://www.aerlingus.com/cgi-bin/obel01im1/bookonline/email.jsp?selectedDay_2=&selectedDay_1=27&selectedChildrenNumber=0&locale=en&selectedSourceAirport_1=AMS&selectedAdultNumber=1&selectedInfantNumber=0&selectedSearchType=FIXED&selectedDestinationAirport_1=ORK&selectedMonth_1=5&selectedMonth_2=&selectedFlightType=ONEWAY&methodToUse=Book%20Now&selectedFareCategory=0&skyscanner_redirectid=8dazuOiYEeOZowBQVrxEjA&tduid=25871bf6c256bce59a21e91ce80af41d)

Q1: Could I use a combination of these two flights? I am not familiar with this process. Does it need rechecking or baggage checking?

Q2: If so, Do I need any type of visa in Amsterdam?

Comment: @Mojtaba You ask some tough ones man. If you wouldn't be transiting at Kiev, this would be a breeze.

Comment: Also, why don't you get into Dublin first and then go to Cork. Or go to cork via bus or train instead?

Comment: @AdityaSomani, You are right. It seems it is better to go to Dublin and avoid transition risk. I preferred Cork because its flights are cheaper (360-400$) and have less waiting time. for example I should wait 17hrs in Dubai to go to Dublin (450$) or wait 2hrs in Istanbul (740$) that is too expensive for me and a little risky.

Comment: @Mojtaba I would suggest you to take the UK visa with that flight if they are similarly priced.

Comment: The two questions belong together, as they are tightly related.  eg, the Visa question can vary significantly depending on whether he needs to collect/re-check bags or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to transit thru the Netherlands as an Iranian Citizen, you will generally need a transit visa. This is clearly stated on the [Goverment.NL](http://www.government.nl/issues/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/short-stay-visas-for-the-netherlands) website and is shown in this [PDF](http://www.government.nl/files/documents-and-publications/publications/2013/11/28/nationals-of-the-following-countries-need-an-airport-transit-visa-to-change-aircraft-at-an-airport-in-a-schengen-country/nationals-of-the-following-countries-need-an-airport-transit-visa.pdf) from the same as well.

There are some exceptions [(Immihelp)](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/requirements-exemptions.html) to this rule even though the [Embassy websites](http://india.nlembassy.org/services/visa/visas-for-the-netherlands-schengen-visas/visas-for-the-netherlands-schengen-visas/minbuza%3ashare/visa-requirements-according-to-nationality/stay-shorter-than-90-days/nationals-who-must-have-an-airport-transit-visa-atv.html) do not state them very clearly, one of these exceptions [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Airport_transit) would be the **Long Stay Type 'D' visa that you hold for Ireland**.

The exception should be perfectly valid in your case and many sources verify this as well.

Note, considering the case of using the two flights (which I beleive would be on different reservations) you can obviously do it, but if your luggage is *not* checked in thru and thru, you will have to collect and re-check in your luggage which would **require** you to pass thru border control and you **will** need a visa in order to do so (a Proper Short Stay Schengen Visa). If you can have your luggage checked in thru, there shouldn't be much else to take care of beside the Ukraine side of things, the Netherlands should be alright.

Comment: There is no “landside transit visa” in the Schengen area, only a regular short-stay visa.

Comment: @Relaxed Apologies for the ambiguity, that was the one I was referring to.